# Why save_to_dir dont work in flow_from_directory In Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, tf.keras, image-preprocessing

Here i want to save the  augmented pictures to a directory.but that didn't happend using the below code.I am  beginner .Please Help.Thanks in advance.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    validation_split=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    brightness_range=[0.2,1.0],
    )

    
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    r'C:\Users\Mahmudul Hasan\Desktop\practice',
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical',
    seed=42,
    subset="training",
    save_to_dir=r"C:\Users\Mahmudul Hasan\Desktop\Augmented data" )
```

Comment: Try to specify `save_prefix=""`, `save_format="png" ` while using flow.

Comment: @Mahmudul Hasan Munna, Did you tried as suggested above? It should work for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`train_datagen.flow_from_directory` gives you a generator. To really generate the image, use this example code:

```
i = 0
for batch in train_datagen.flow_from_directory(input_dir, target_size=(150, 150),
class_mode='binary', shuffle=False, 
save_to_dir=output_dir, save_prefix='aug'):
i += 1
if i > 20: 
    break
```